# Copying figures out of a string into their own cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Copying figures out of a string into their own cells.

I’ve got a column in a spreadsheet that shows the path to log files along with how many times a search string appears in the log file for that day. What I’d like to do is separate out each occurrence of this number into separate columns.

Here’s a shortened example that just covers a few days, normally the cell would contain entriesfor  30 days. The number I want to separate out is the one following by a : normally this is after the date but for the log file from today there is no date and the number will follow after the log file name.

/cygdrive/c/fol1/302047/file.log:**0**/cygdrive/c/fol1/302047/file.log.2022-09-07:**2**/cygdrive/c/fol1/302047/file.log.2022-09-08:**3**/cygdrive/c/fol1/302047/file.log.2022-09-09:**1**/cygdrive/c/fol1/302047/file.log.2022-09-10:**0**

So in this example I would have separate columns with these numbers in 0, 2, 3, 1, 0

What formula can I use to do this? As the number always follows a : could I use this to pinpoint the number and pull it out into a separate cell for occurance?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then could try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,":"),"/",,,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. What I’m really after is for each number to be in it’s own column, so 0 in column B, 2 in column C, 3 in column D etc. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Reck Then just ignore `TEXTJOIN()` function. Try `TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,":"),"/",,,1)`.

Comment: That seems to have done it thanks. I’ve never heard of textsplit before and didn’t know you could create an array of columns like that.

The only issue I have now is that I can’t create a pivot table based on the textsplit array values. Do you know of a way around that?

Comment: @Reck If my answer solve your current thread then please tick mark it to treat as closed. Then ask a separate question with sufficient sample data. That is way actually stackoverflow recommend.

Comment: It does Harun, thanks for your help.